# How do I build an ASP.Net core web api Enpoint that handles query parameters with an equal '=' sign

Tags: c#, angular, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to take take an endpoint that is built from this Angular typescript frontend code

```
  getPartNumbersFromManufacture(manufactureNameId : Number)
  {
    let parameter = new HttpParams().set("FKManufactureNameId", manufactureNameId.toString()) 
    return this.http.get<ManufacturePartNumber[]>(this.manufactureUrl + '/PartNumber', {params: parameter}).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

This results in a request that looks like this:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5001/api/Manufacture/PartNumber?FKManufactureNameId=14703
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:5001
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The .netcore C# code looks like this, the endpoint is being hit, but the manufactureNameID is always =0, and if i try to change it to a string it is null.

```
    [Route("api/Manufacture")]
    public class ManufactureController : ControllerBase
    { ...
        [HttpGet("PartNumber/{FKManufactureNameId=manufactureNameID}")]
        public IEnumerable<Views.ManufacturePartNumber> PartNumbers(int manufactureNameID) //pass the manufacture id from the frontend and get the part numbers associated with this manufacturer
        {
            TrackingContext context = new TrackingContext();
            IEnumerable<ManufacturePartNumber> manufacturePartNumbers = context.ManufacturePartNumber.Where(n => n.FkManufactureNameId == manufactureNameID);

            List<Views.ManufacturePartNumber> manufacturePartNumberView = new List<Views.ManufacturePartNumber>();
            for (int i = 0; i < manufacturePartNumbers.Count(); i++)
            {
                manufacturePartNumberView.Add(new Views.ManufacturePartNumber(manufacturePartNumbers.ElementAt(i)));
            }
            return manufacturePartNumberView;
        }
   ...}
```

What am I doing wrong, I want my C# code to process this query parameter that has an equal sign since this seems to be the standard way that "HttPClient" class builds the query parameters when passed a "HttpParams" object. I know how to handle no '=' but I'm guessing the '=' is the new standard/best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your api declaration seems it is not accurate.

This is is what I believe you want to do:

```
 [HttpGet("PartNumber")] /* <--- */
 public IEnumerable<Views.ManufacturePartNumber> 
       PartNumbers(/* --> */[FromQuery]int manufactureNameID) 
        {...
```

You want a parameter to be taken from **QueryString** therefore you indicate so with `[FromQuery]` attribute next to the parameter, like:

`[FromQuery]int manufactureNameID`

Also your `[HttpGet]` Attribute does not need to add anything else but the  "Method Routing" which in this case is  `[HttpGet("PartNumber")]`

Comment: Small change I had to add to your code: I had to to put "FKManufactureNameId" in the function parameter, not "manufactureNameID". If I leave "manufactureNameID" then I still have the same 0 & null problem. Would you update your answer and I'll accept it?